# Area EPITECH Project

Tags: app

Area EPITECH

This project is a clone of Make or IFTTT.
This project is made with a group of 5 developers.
All the developers working on the project are EPITECH students.

For the moment, at the middle of the project, we are good.

Thanks

Comment: Is this project going to use or connect to the Stack Exchange API, Teams or one of our sites in the network? If yes, can you spend a few words on what that woud be in your question?